# Outputting data to modals from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, bootstrap-modal

How to arrange the output of information from the "JSON" file into a certain model window. Each individual window has its own information, depending on the pressed block.

The fact is that there are a lot of such windows on the page, and it would not be reasonable to display them all in html.

I wrote following the example of the code taken from open sources.
My code HTML & JS: index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Cards</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .iframe_video {
            height: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 56.2%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .iframe_video iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="card-group" style="margin-top: 20px;">
              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Example_image.svg/320px-Example_image.svg.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul id="testModal" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li id="modal1" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block11">Block 1.1</li>
                    <li id="modal2" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block12">Block 1.2</li>
                    <li id="modal3" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block13">Block 1.3</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Example_image.svg/320px-Example_image.svg.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li id="modal21" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block21">Block 2.1</li>
                    <li id="modal22" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block22">Block 2.2</li>
                    <li id="modal23" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block23">Block 2.3</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="card">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Example_image.svg/320px-Example_image.svg.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li id="modal31" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block31">Block 3.1</li>
                    <li id="modal32" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block32">Block 3.2</li>
                    <li id="modal33" class="list-group-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#block33">Block 3.3</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>

    <div class="container">
         <!-- Sample output from JSON. But without proper experience, I could not assemble this constructo -->
        <p id="titleModal1"></p>
        <p id="descModal1"></p>
        <p id="data111"></p>
        <p id="data112"></p>
        <p id="titleMovieBlock12"></p>
        <p id="movieLinkBlock12"></p>
        <p id="titleMovieBlock13"></p>
        <p id="movieLinkBlock13"></p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Start Script -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlhttp, clickId, newModal
        
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
         // here i get id li on which i click
            $('li').click(function(){
              console.log(this.id);
              });
              
              /* Here I was trying to assign to a variable the output of the modal window itself
              $('...').click(function() {
                newModal = '<div class="modal fade" id="block11" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">'+
                    '<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">'+
                    '<div class="modal-content">'+
                    '<div class="modal-header">'+
                    '<h5 class="modal-title display-6" id="titleModal1">Title Block 1.1</h5>'+
                    '<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="modal-body">'+
                    '<div class="container">'+
                    '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-sm">'+
                    '<p id="descModal1">Description Block 1.1</p>'+
                    '<br>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<hr>'+
                    '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-lg">'+
                    '<div class="display-6">Specs</div>'+
                    '<table class="table table-hover">'+
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<th scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">Specs 1.1 #1</th>'+
                    '<td id="data111">Value 1.1 #1</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '</table>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-lg">'+
                    '<div class="display-6">Art #</div>'+
                    '<table class="table table-hover">'+
                    '<tr>'+
                    '<th scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">Specs 1.1 #2</th>'+
                    '<td id="data112">Value 1.1 #2</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '</table>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
                $(this).html(newModal);
              });
              */
              
              
        /* here is data output from json by certain div #id . Following the example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp */
   
            var myModal = JSON.parse('{"titleModal1":"Title Modal 1.1","descModal1":"Description Block 1.1","specs1":{"data111":"Value 1.1 #1","data112":"Value 1.1 #2"},"movie1":{"titleMovieBlock12":"Title Block 1.2 : youtube","movieLinkBlock12":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/r5fPGI1jerc"},"movie2":{"titleMovieBlock13":"Title Block 1.3 youtube","movieLinkBlock13":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/IUN664s7N-c"},"titleModal2":"Title Modal 2.1","descModal2":"Description Block 2.1","specs2":{"data211":"Value 2.1 #1","data212":"Value 2.1 #2"},"movie5":{"titleMovieBlock51":"Title Block 2.2 : youtube","movieLinkBlock52":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/r5fPGI1jerc"},"movie6":{"titleMovieBlock61":"Title Block 2.3 youtube","movieLinkBlock62":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/IUN664s7N-c"},"titleModal3":"Title Modal 3.1","descModal3":"Description Block 3.1","specs3":{"data311":"Value 3.1 #1","data312":"Value 3.1 #2"},"movie7":{"titleMovieBlock71":"Title Block 3.2 : youtube","movieLinkBlock72":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/r5fPGI1jerc"},"movie8":{"titleMovieBlock81":"Title Block 3.3 youtube","movieLinkBlock82":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/IUN664s7N-c"}}');
            document.getElementById("titleModal1").innerHTML = myModal.titleModal1;
            document.getElementById("descModal1").innerHTML = myModal.descModal1;
            document.getElementById("data111").innerHTML = myModal.specs1.data111;
            document.getElementById("data112").innerHTML = myModal.specs1.data112;
            document.getElementById("titleMovieBlock12").innerHTML = myModal.movie1.titleMovieBlock12;
            document.getElementById("movieLinkBlock12").innerHTML = myModal.movie1.movieLinkBlock12;
            document.getElementById("titleMovieBlock13").innerHTML = myModal.movie2.titleMovieBlock13;
            document.getElementById("movieLinkBlock13").innerHTML = myModal.movie2.movieLinkBlock13;
       
       
    </script>
    
    <!-- Stop Script -->


    <!-- Start Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="block11" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title display-6" id="titleModal1">Title Block 1.1</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p id="descModal1">Description Block 1.1</p>
                    <br>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="display-6">Specs</div>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">Specs 1.1 #1</th>
                          <td id="data111">Value 1.1 #1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <div class="display-6">Art #</div>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row" style="font-weight: bold;">Specs 1.1 #2</th>
                          <td id="data112">Value 1.1 #2</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="block12" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title display-6" id="titleMovieBlock12">Title Block 1.2 : youtube</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="iframe_video">
                        <iframe id="movieLinkBlock12" width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r5fPGI1jerc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="block13" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title display-6" id="exampleModalLabel">Title Block 1.3 : youtube #2</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="iframe_video">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IUN664s7N-c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Stop Modal -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you can't put everything on one page then maybe you should consider using a tabbing/paging component

Comment: It seems to me that this will only complicate the filling process, because if I understand you correctly, then it is necessary to create a separate file for each modal window ?! Or I misunderstood you ?!

Comment: no it's not necessary to have many files. Since you're using bootstrap you can use this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation and your time, but unfortunately this is not what I would like.